# SwiftUI not showing the correct view depending of a boolean value

Tags: firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm running into a small but frustrating bug using SwiftUI and Firebase, although I don't think Firebase is an issue.

I have some simple logic when displaying a `welcomeScreen` and a `mapScreen`:

```
struct HomeScreen: View {

   @EnvironmentObject var authenticationViewModel: AuthenticationViewModel
   
   @State private var isUserLoggedIn = false
   @State private var isLoggedInCancelable: AnyCancellable? = nil
   
   // ...

   var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if isUserLoggedIn {
                mapScreen
            } else {
                welcomeScreen
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            isLoggedInCancelable = authenticationViewModel.publisher.sink { loggedIn in
                print("is user logged in: \(loggedIn)")
                isUserLoggedIn = loggedIn
            }
        }
   }

   // ...

}
```

AuthenticationViewModel.swift

```
class AuthenticationViewModel: ObservableObject {
        
    @Published private var listener: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle? = nil
    //@Published var isUserLoggedIn: Bool = Auth.auth().currentUser != nil

    
    private let subject = CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never>(false)
    var publisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
        subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }

    func listenToAuthState() {
        listener = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { [self] _, user in
            subject.send(user != nil)
            // isUserLoggedIn = user != nil
        }
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

This is the problem. I'm listening to the state of the Firebase `User`. I receive the correct `true`/`false` value when the user is logged in or not respectively. The thing is, when I login, I print `is user logged in: true`, but the `welcomeScreen` is displayed, which doesn't quite make sense since `isUserLoggedIn == true`. I also tried using the commented `@Published` variable inside `AuthenticationViewModel` and use that instead of the the `@State` in `HomeScreen`, but no luck.

Any ideas on how to fix this bug will be greatly appreciated.

---

**UPDATE:**

I have noticed the issue is not coming from any of this, but from a `sheet` I am displaying based on the state of user.

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isUserLoggedIn) {
   // content
}
```

It seems like this makes it false for some reason.

Comment: to try to isolate the problem, could you use `.onAppear { DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) { isUserLoggedIn = true } }` and see if that works.

Comment: That kind of did the trick, with a second delay though. Would you mind elaborating on why the delay works and the good old `DispatchQueue.main.async` doesn't?

Comment: you mean, in your `.onAppear{...}` code, you tried `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.isUserLoggedIn = loggedIn }` and that does not work?  The use of `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter...` is just for testing, not to be used in production.

Comment: Yes. I tried that and no luck.

Comment: I have updated my question. That was not quite the issue, the issue seems to be a `sheet` I'm presenting.

Comment: Interesting, why are the sheet and the mapScreen connected to the same variable in the first place?

Comment: I want to show a map with a bottom sheet when the user is logged in. When the user logs out, just the welcome screen.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, I would probably just attach it to a different variable entirely then & just listen to when the isUserLoggedIn changes to display the bottomSheet or not.

Comment: try using `.sheet(item: $isUserLoggedIn) { isloged in  ....}` where you declare `@State private var isUserLoggedIn: Bool?`

Comment: Ok. I believe I figured it out. A mix of all your guys' answers helped a lot. Thank you. I'll leave the question open to see if someone comes up with a better solution.

Comment: Try replacing `.onAppear` with `.task`, maybe that's all you need.